# Sort Pivot Table Descending By Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

i have a macro which create pivot table from a data source then makes some filters and edit rows and columns Labels.

My pivot table looks like this.

[image]

What i want to do now is, i select the drop down arrow on Row Labels 
[image]

and Click 
**More Sort Options**

[image]

Then i select **Descending (Z to A) by:** and choose **Sum of Actual Net USD Revenue**

[image]

I am using this code

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Workbooks("Load.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
PvtTbl.PivotFields("COUNTRY").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Actual Net USD Revenue"
```

I have tried many solutions on net but noone was working for me. If i sort based on Ascending or Descending just on one column for example then it works but i want to add the criteria Descending by Sum of Actual Net USD Revenue.

Any Suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to see if you can get the code that way? This would be the quickest way to go.